# Pine Script - Conditional Plot Style

Tags: pine-script

I couldn't find an answer for this anywhere; not even in the official documentation. I've tried coding it myself but it's not working, so maybe it might not be possible.

In the example below, you can plot with conditional colors:

```
//STACKED EMAs
    MA1 = ta.ema(close, 5)
    MA2 = ta.ema(close, 8)
    MA3 = ta.ema(close, 13)
    MA4 = ta.ema(close, 21)
    MA5 = ta.ema(close, 34)
    MA_Stack_Up = (MA1 > MA2) and (MA2 > MA3) and (MA3 > MA4) and (MA4 > MA5)
    
    //CONDITIONS
    Uptrend = MA_Stack_Up
    Reversal = ((MA1 < MA2) and (MA2 > MA3)) or ((MA1 > MA2) and (MA2 < MA3))
    
    //COLOR CODING
    Bar_Color = Uptrend ? color.new(color.green, 25) : Reversal ? color.new(color.yellow, 25) : color.new(color.red, 25)

//PLOTS
plot(1, color=Bar_Color, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3)
```

Is it possible to have a conditional statement that changes the style of the plot?

Example:

```
B_Style = Cond1 ? plot.style_line : Cond2 ? plot.style_cross : plot.style_circles

//PLOTS
plot(1, color=Bar_Color, style=B_Style, linewidth=3)
```

Comment: Looks like not possible. I can provide you a workaround but that would have multiple `plot()` calls.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the workaround, if it's not too much work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible at the moment. A possible workaround would be using a variable as a condition to your `plot()` and having multiple `plot` calls for different styles.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

myRsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
cond = myRsi < 40 ? 1 : myRsi < 60 ? 2 : na
plot(cond == 1 ? myRsi : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)
plot(cond == 2 ? myRsi : na, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=2)
hline(40, color=color.red)
hline(60, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Shame it's not possible yet but thanks very much for showing the workaround. Will try to incorporate it into my code.